# Unable to use the kibana-time-plugin

Tags: kibana-5

I am using kibana 5.4.3. I have created dashboards with time as one of the axis in many visualizations. I need the time filter for the dashboard to be useful. But when i embed the dashboard on my website, the time filter is not visible. **I tried the kibana-time-plugin([github link to that plugin](https://github.com/nreese/kibana-time-plugin)). I followed the steps in the readme markdown. But i am not able to use the plugin. Please help me get the plugin working on my dashboard.**